# Viewpage stop swiping in a certain direction

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How can I stop viewpager from scrolling in one direction only. For example, allow swipes only to the right, but not to the left. I am absolutely stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated. To note that I need to get this to work for Android version 2.2, so I am using the compatibilty library for ViewPager.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to make your own ViewPager that extends the original ViewPager and override the onTouchEvent method

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    float lastX = 0;

    boolean lockScroll = false;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            lastX = ev.getX();
            lockScroll = false;
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            if (lastX > ev.getX()) {
                lockScroll = false;
            } else {
                lockScroll = true;
            }

            lastX = ev.getX();
            break;
        }

        lastX = ev.getX();

        if(lockScroll) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Hi Ali - unfortunately, this does not work. I even tried the onTouchEvent event, but alas, no joy.

Comment: Another trick, when you scroll to the next view, delete the first one. I'll update after few minutes.

Comment: super buggy, esp if there are offsets.