# Android - Viewpager Customization

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using a Viewpager for using user profiles. I have few requirements for Viewpager.

1. I want it to be locked in one direction. i.e. I want user should be able to swipe left only to load new fragments. Once he has moved to next fragment, he shouldn't be able to go back to previous fragment. I saw so many answers but could not infer a apt answer. 
   [How to disable ViewPager from swiping in one direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602369/how-to-disable-viewpager-from-swiping-in-one-direction) User says he was unable to get the required result.
2. I want to use some good animation for fragment page change transition effect rather than simple sliding. I saw JazzyViewPager - https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager but was unable to understand how to incorporate in my existing project.

In case, it is possible I was thinking of using a pan for some 3D horizontal rolling (Not a priority though).

Answer (score 1):

First Problem's solution  [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224581/viewpage-stop-swiping-in-a-certain-direction) and 
[Another Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276846/one-side-viewpager-swiping-only)

Second you can add Transition effect to fragment what you expect 
step by step explanation give [here](http://howrobotswork.wordpress.com/2013/06/27/create-viewpager-transitions-a-pagertransformer-example/)

and also see [This](http://mrigaen.blogspot.in/2013/11/create-fade-infade-out-effect-with.html)