# How to save some value and destroy a fragment after swiping?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have several fragments. I want them to come one after another as `ViewPager`. If i swipe right then a fragment will be destroyed storing a value "yes"  and if i swipe left it will destroy storing a value "no" and next fragment will appear. I tried `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` but not getting desired result. I have google a lot but unable to do as I want.

Suppose I have 3 fragments 1,2,3. 
1 is the first fragment. If I swipe right/left fragment 1 will destroy storing a value and fragment 2 will appear, and so on. When swiping to last fragment, a Dialog box will pop up with completion message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `ViewPager` does not destroy your fragment, when you swipe from fragmet 1 to fragment 2. However, if you swipe from fragment 2 to fragment 3, fragment 1 is destroyed. This also applies to when you swipe from fragment 2 to fragment 1. In that case, fragment 3 is destroyed.

If you want to store a value between swipes, you should probably use the `onPause` callback method of the respective fragment.

Comment: if i swipe 1 to 2,then 3 ,1 will be destroy but when i swipe back destroyed fragments comes again...Specially i want to destroy a fragment forever after swiping.... @Marcus

Comment: Yes, your `ViewPager` recreates the Fragments if the user decides to "swipe back". If you want to stop your `ViewPager` from swiping in a particular direction, thus stopping it from recreating fragments, you could have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224581/viewpage-stop-swiping-in-a-certain-direction). @user3751576